# how to run Sample camera program in Android , to take pictures

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to write a Android Program for Camera that captures pictures. I written code in such a way when I click a button, it should be captured, but noting is happeneing. Button click happens , but control doesnot come to "onPictureTaken". I am pasting my code here:

### Activity

```
package com.andr.sai.camerademo;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class camerademo extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
 {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 SurfaceView mSurfaceView ;
 SurfaceHolder    mSurfaceHolder;
 boolean mPreviewRunning;
 Camera  mCamera;
 Bitmap bitmap = null; 
 Button b1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_surface);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

  @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
   System.out.println("111111111111111111111111");
   Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() 
   {


    public void onPictureTaken(byte[]imageData, Camera arg1) {
     System.out.println("2222222222222222222222222222222222222");
     BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
                 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, opt); 


    }

   };


   }
        }
        );


    }

 @Override
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int arg1, int w, int h) {
  if (mPreviewRunning) {
   mCamera.stopPreview();
   }
   Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
   p.setPreviewSize(w, h);
   mCamera.setParameters(p);
   try {
   mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
   } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
   mCamera.startPreview();
   mPreviewRunning = true;

 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
  mCamera = Camera.open(); 

 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
  mCamera.stopPreview();
  mPreviewRunning = false;
  mCamera.release();



 }




 public void onDraw(Canvas c)
  {

  c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
  c.drawBitmap( bitmap, 10, 10, null);

 }

}
```

### camera_surface.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<SurfaceView 
   android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="10dip"
   android:layout_weight="1"
> 
</SurfaceView> 

<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Gettt"
   android:id="@+id/b1"

></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

In debug mode I ran this one and I am getting the following debug strings:

```
08-24 17:43:41.293: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(30):   error: -2
08-24 17:43:41.303: ERROR/MediaPlayer(30): Unable to to create media player
08-24 17:43:41.303: ERROR/CameraService(30): Failed to load CameraService sounds.
08-24 17:43:41.334: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(30):   error: -2
08-24 17:43:41.344: ERROR/MediaPlayer(30): Unable to to create media player
08-24 17:43:41.344: ERROR/CameraService(30): Failed to load CameraService sounds.
08-24 17:43:41.354: DEBUG/CameraService(30): Client::Client X (pid 421)
08-24 17:43:41.364: DEBUG/CameraService(30): CameraService::connect X
08-24 17:43:41.364: DEBUG/CameraService(30): getParameters(picture-format=jpeg;picture-size=213x350;preview-format=yuv422sp;preview-frame-rate=15;preview-size=176x144)
08-24 17:43:41.445: DEBUG/CameraService(30): setParameters(preview-size=320x432;preview-format=yuv422sp;picture-size=213x350;picture-format=jpeg;preview-frame-rate=15)
08-24 17:43:41.445: DEBUG/CameraHardwareStub(30): initHeapLocked: preview size=320x432
08-24 17:43:41.455: DEBUG/CameraService(30): setPreviewDisplay(0xe1f0) (pid 421)
08-24 17:43:41.464: DEBUG/CameraService(30): startPreview (pid 421)
08-24 17:43:41.464: DEBUG/CameraService(30): startCameraMode(0) (pid 421)
08-24 17:43:41.464: DEBUG/CameraService(30): startPreviewMode (pid 421)
```

Can u help me how to run Sample camera program in Android , to take pictures.

Comment: @Android_pro...  You should up-vote a answer if its useful to you or can give  comment whether that works or not, so that others can take benefit from it. Also if you have got the answer then you can add it here.

Answer (score 2):

i dont see a call to
takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback).

In onclick add Camera.takepicture

Answer (score 0):

```
package makemachine.android.examples;
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast; 

public class PhotoCaptureExample extends Activity 
 {
protected Button _button;
protected ImageView _image;
protected TextView _field;
protected String _path;
protected boolean _taken;

protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN   = "photo_taken";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.image );
    _field = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.field );
    _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button );
    _button.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler() );

    _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images   /make_machine_example.jpg";
}

public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    public void onClick( View view ){
        Log.i("MakeMachine", "ButtonClickHandler.onClick()" );
        startCameraActivity();
    }
}

protected void startCameraActivity()
{
    Log.i("MakeMachine", "startCameraActivity()" );
    File file = new File( _path );
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "resultCode: " + resultCode );
    switch( resultCode )
    {
        case 0:
            Log.i( "MakeMachine", "User cancelled" );
            break;

        case -1:
            onPhotoTaken();
            break;
    }
}

protected void onPhotoTaken()
{
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onPhotoTaken" );

    _taken = true;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );

    _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    _field.setVisibility( View.GONE );
}

@Override 
protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onRestoreInstanceState()");
    if( savedInstanceState.getBoolean( PhotoCaptureExample.PHOTO_TAKEN ) ) {
        onPhotoTaken();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    switch(keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
     Toast.makeText(PhotoCaptureExample.this, "Pressed Camera Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
     Toast.makeText(PhotoCaptureExample.this, "Pressed 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
     Toast.makeText(PhotoCaptureExample.this, "Pressed Home Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
     Toast.makeText(PhotoCaptureExample.this, "Pressed Back Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     Intent result = new Intent("Complete");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {
    outState.putBoolean( PhotoCaptureExample.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken );
}
```

}